# Update Datepicker date via number of days in Input Field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am looking to change the date of the a datepicker `id="datepicker_end"` based on the number of days entered into an input field `id="totaldays"`.

The input field `id="totaldays"` has 2 functions

1) It calculates the number of days between 2 datepickers (This works now, see JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Deif/KLpq7/211/) - I want to keep this functionality.

2) If the user decides to enter the number of days directly into the input field then I want the 2nd datepicker `id="datepicker_end"` to update based on the amount of days entered into the field.

The concept here is that the user can enter the amount of days they want or choose between 2 dates...

My JSFiddle is as follows http://jsfiddle.net/Deif/KLpq7/211/

I can't find any good examples so hope I am explaining it OK above.

Comment: This should help you out.  Make sure to open "view source" below the demo.  http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: Dom, yep thats what I have working now in my JSFIddle, I am not sure how to edit the field to get it to update the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
function days() {
            var a = new Date($("#datepicker_start").val()),
                b = new Date($("#datepicker_end").val()),
                c = 24*60*60*1000,
                diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((a - b)/(c)));
            $("#totaldays").val(diffDays);
}

function formatDate(_d){
     var d = new Date(_d);
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    if(curr_date < 10)
        curr_date = "0" + curr_date;

    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    if(curr_month < 10)
        curr_month = "0" + curr_month;

    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();   
    return curr_month + '/' + curr_date + '/' + curr_year;
}

$('#totaldays').change(function(){        
    if($(this).val() != ''){
        var days = $(this).val();
        var start= new Date($("#datepicker_start").val());
        var newStart = start.setDate(start.getDate() + parseInt(days));    
        $("#datepicker_end").val(formatDate(newStart));
    }else{
        $("#datepicker_end").val($("#datepicker_start").val());
    }

});

$('.datepicker')
    .datepicker({format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'})
    .on('changeDate', function(ev){
        days();
        $(this).datepicker('hide').blur();
});
```

DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/KLpq7/218/

Comment: awesome Dom, thanks a lot mate! that works like a charm! Made my night!